# Encoding the existence of an element of a type for which there exists some proof of irrelevant contents

Tags: logic, type-theory

I'm studying encoding math (and sets in this particular case) in the calculus of constructions. So let's say there are types $S, T$ (so $S : *, T: *$), a predicate $V : S \rightarrow *$ and a function $F : \Pi x : S. Vx \rightarrow T $. If one considers $Vx$ to be a witness of $x : S$ belonging to the corresponding subset of $S$ (where $S$ is interpreted as a set), then $F$ can be interpreted as a function from a subset of $S$ to $T$. Now, how can the surjectivity of this function be encoded?

I've come up with two slightly different options:
$$
\Pi y : T. \exists x : S. \exists p : Vx. Fxp = y,
$$
and
$$
\Pi y : T. \exists x : S. Vx \land \Pi p : Vx. F x p = y.
$$

It looks like the second one is at least as strong as the first one (indeed, one can build a term of the first type when given a term of the second type). And, moreover, while the first one guarantees the existence of a proof $p$ of $x$ belonging to $V$ such that $Fxp = y$, the second one guarantees that this proof exists, and, more than that, is also guarantees that the equality holds for *any* such proof. Does it make a difference?

---

The theory I'm working in does not have first-class existential quantification or $\Sigma$-types. Instead, $\exists x : S. P x$ is encoded as $\Pi \alpha : *. (\Pi x : S. Px \rightarrow \alpha) \rightarrow \alpha$.

Comment: I'd have thought the first is easier to work with, and better mirrors what is meant by 'surjective'. In set theoretic terms all we care about is that each $y \in T$ is of the form $F(x)$ for some $x \in V$; it doesn't matter how we came to know that $x \in V$. This kind-of mirrors what happens in HoTT, where '$f$ is a surjection' means $\Pi y \exists x \cdots$, not $\Pi y \Sigma x \cdots$. [I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer because I haven't really worked with CoC so I don't claim to know what I'm talking about.]

Comment: What do you mean by "can be interpreted as a function from a subset of $S$ to $T$"? From the type you have given, $F$ is a dependent function: it takes two arguments $x:S$ and $p: V x$ (i.e., it is only defined for $p \in S$ such that $p \in V x$ holds). It returns a value $F\,x\,p:T$.

Comment: @RobArthan exactly! It's defined for $x:S$ for which we can provide a $p : Vx$, so if you consider $V$ to define a subset of $S$ (all those $x$ for which there exists $Vx$), then you get that interpretation. As an example, take $S = \mathbb{N}$ and $V = \lambda x:S. \{ x \text{ is even } \}$. Then you get a function that's defined just on even nats.

Comment: In your example,$V\,x$ is a truth value (of some kind - what kind depends on the details of your type theory). $V$ represents a set of a natural numbers, but $V\,x$ does not.

Comment: Yep, but since a witness of $Vx$ is required for the function, it guarantees that $x$ belongs to the set represented by $V$.

Comment: What guarantees that $x$ belongs to the set represented by $V$? In the example, we've been discussing, $F\,x$ is defined for all $x \in \Bbb{N}$.